# How can I add datepicker into jQuery modal dialog box in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I add a datepicker into my modal dialog box. but when I click on the date picker, it always display behind the modal dialog box. How can I load it inside the jQuery modal dialog box? Following is my code to load date picker...

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "event[start_at]", "", :valid_date_check => "date.getDay() != 0 && date.getDay() != 6  && date.stripTime() > (new Date()).stripTime()" %>
```

I am using [date picker](http://calendardateselect.googlecode.com/svn/tags/calendar_date_select) plug-in in my application..

Comment: Try making the datepicker css z-index higher than the modal's

Comment: @ Barlow can u put this as an answer? thank u.. it is working now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the z-index of the modal box is higher than the datepicker

make the css z-index for the datepicker higher than the modal box.

example css:

```
.modal {
  z-index: 9990;
}

.datepicker {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Hope this helps.